# How to close first dropdown when user click on second dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I am using 2 codrops dropdwon menus in single page. I want to close the first drop down menu   when user clicks on the 2nd drop down menu.

I am using below code in my project.

```
<select id="Select1" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Menu 1</option>
    <option value="7" >subMenu1</option>
    <option value="8" >subMenu2</option>
    <option value="9" >subMenu3</option></select>

// 2nd Menu
<select id="Select2" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Menu 2</option>
    <option value="2" >subMenu1</option>
    <option value="5" >subMenu2</option></select>
```

.aspx Page Java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Select1').dropdown({
            gutter: 5,
            stack: false,
            delay: 100,
            slidingIn: 100
        });
        $('#Select2').dropdown({
            gutter: 5,
            stack: false,
            delay: 100,
            slidingIn: 100
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to close `Select1` when user click on `Select2`. Please give me suggestion how to do this.

- **[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/oye7bq5q/)**

Comment: By "close `Select1`", do you mean making `Select1` disabled?

Comment: @ekad - close means - I want to collapse-up all the menu option -  you can see [demo here] (http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/oye7bq5q/)

Comment: The plugin itself has no option for it directly unless you mess around with the source code

Comment: where is the plugin from?

Comment: @Pete - from codrops -http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/

Comment: Looking at source, this plugin does not provide this option, neither does it provide an option to hook to an event. Use some other plugin for dropdown, maybe bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns or jquery ui selectmenu http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the plugin doesn't have any options for an `onclick` event so if you add the following code to the load event:

```
$('.cd-dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.cd-active').not($(this))
            .removeClass('cd-active')
            .children('ul').css('height', 'auto')
            .children('li').css('top', 0);
});
```

It will toggle the open and close when you click.

However you will then need to change the script file as it is using an `opened` flag and we can't effect this so search for the `_initEvents` and add this as the first line in the `this.selectlabel.on` function:

```
self.opened = self.dd.hasClass('cd-active');
```

[It should all then work! Click for example](http://jsfiddle.net/oye7bq5q/18/)

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for onchange event** ..if any body want's it

[**Fiddle Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/oye7bq5q/13/)

1) Place Select1 in one DIV

2) Define onOptionSelect function for Select2

3)  on onOptionSelect event hide DIV of select1

Code here for Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('#Select1').dropdown({
        gutter: 1,
        stack: false
    });
    $('#Select2').dropdown({
        gutter: 1,
        stack: false,
        onOptionSelect :function(opt) { 

        $('#Select1Place').hide();    

        }
    });
});
```

For HTML

```
<div>
        <div style='float:left;width:250px;'>
            <div id="Select1Place"><!-- New DIV for holding position of select-->
<select id="Select1"  name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>The drop down menu</option>
    <option value="1" class="icon-monkey">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="icon-bear">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="icon-squirrel">Choice 3</option>
    <option value="4" class="icon-elephant">Choice 4</option>
</select>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div style='float:left;width:150px;padding-top:170px;'>
<select id="Select2" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>The drop down menu</option>
    <option value="1" class="icon-monkey">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="icon-bear">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="icon-squirrel">Choice 3</option>
    <option value="4" class="icon-elephant">Choice 4</option>
</select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3577774  Let me know you want onclick or onchange?

Comment: I want to close `select1` dropdown when user `OnClick` on second dropdown`select2`

Comment: ok that's right this answer is not for your solution but keep it if someone else want on change event extension

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the first selector when the second one is clicked. If you do not want to hide it, just disable it, then mrts17 has the solution for you in the answer above.

```
<div id = 'Select1Div'>
    <select id="Select1" class="cd-select">
        <option value="-1" selected>Menu 1</option>
        <option value="7" >subMenu1</option>
        <option value="8" >subMenu2</option>
        <option value="9" >subMenu3</option></select>        

    </div>
    <select id="Select2" class="cd-select">
        <option value="-1" selected>Menu 2</option>
        <option value="2" >subMenu1</option>
        <option value="5" >subMenu2</option></select>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#"Select2').change(function(){
                $('Select1Div').hide(); 
                   });
        });
    </script>
```